# How to sum values in a nested array based on element values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>1.0},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>2},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>3.0},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>4.0},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>5.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>6.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>7.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>8.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>9},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>10.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>11},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>12.5},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>13.1},
 {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>14.5}]
```

And I would like to loop through each of these elements and sum the values based on the values that are assigned to the other two keys, `:metric_type` and `:key`, and am trying to get results that look like this:

```
[{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=50.1},
{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>58.5}]
```

I played around with `inject` and `reduce` but have not been able to come up with what I am looking for.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". You're asking for code but haven't showed us your attempt, or explained why it doesn't work. That makes your question off-topic. Show us the minimum code that demonstrates what you tried and why it didn't work, then we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us name your array as `a`

```
result = a.group_by { |x| x[:key] }.values.map do |v|
  v.reduce do |a, b|
    a.merge(b) do |k, v1, v2|
      k.eql?(:value) ? v1 + v2 : v1
    end
  end
end

p result
```

Output

```
[{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>50.1}, {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>58.5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some kind of interesting one-line solution, but I think this is short enough and readable. This assumes your array of hashes is named `arr`:

```rb
females = {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>0.0} 
males = {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>0.0} 

arr.each_with_object([females, males]) do |hsh|
  males[:value] += hsh[:value] if hsh[:key] == "male"
  females[:value] += hsh[:value] if hsh[:key] == "female"
end
```

Obviously, this only works if you are only supporting the two `key`s listed in your example. If there are potentially others, then you'll need to use one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` holds your array, here are two ways of doing that.

**Use [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge)**

```
arr.partition { |h| h[:key]=="female" }.
    map do |a|
      tot = a.sum { |h| h[:value] }
      a.first.merge(value: tot)
    end
  #=> [{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>50.1},
  #    {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>58.5}]
```

**Use the forms of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:key]=>g) do |_,o,n|
    o.merge(n) { |k,oo,nn| k==:value ? (oo+nn) : oo }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on newest Ruby (or has Rails) you could do:

```
array.group_by { |x| x[:key] }.map do |key, collection|
  collection.first.merge(value: collection.sum { |x| x[:value] })
end
# => [{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>50.1}, 
#     {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>58.5}]
```

Old ruby, you could do:

```
array.group_by { |x| x[:key] }.map do |key, collection|
  collection.first.merge(value: collection.map { |x| x[:value] }.inject(:+))
end
# => [{:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"female", :value=>50.1}, 
#     {:metric_type=>"gender", :key=>"male", :value=>58.5}]
```